# Automapper Base type, dervied type DTO Mapping

Tags: automapper, automapper-6

I have the following classes:

```
public class Entity 
{
}

public class Company : Entity
{
}

public class Person : Entity
{
}

public class SomeOther
{
   public Entity A { get; set; }
}
```

And the following DTOs:

```
public class EntityDTO
{
}

public class SomeOtherDTO
{
   public EntityDTO A { get; set; }
}
```

And the following Mappings:

```
CreateMap<Person, EntityDTO>();
CreateMap<Company, EntityDTO>();
```

Is there any way of doing `CreateMap<Entity, EntityDTO>()` and tell Automapper to use the relevant mapping based on the derived type?

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Mapping-inheritance.html

Comment: I should have mentioned I'm using Queryable Extensions (projectto). This doesnt seem to work with the example as in the above link

Comment: Yes, because EF6 doesn't really support that. Try to write a query that does what you want without AM. If that works then you can do that with AM too, otherwise...